# Custom GitLab not working with remote pull

Tags: gitlab, clone

I've been looking for answers about a very curious case im facing right now. I work for a client, whom has a custom GitLab server, and i'm being asked tu automate some tasks that require som git pulls and clones. The thing is that i can't do neither clone nor pull from the repos they provided me. So far thit is what i've tried:

**git clone**

```
git clone https://git.someorganization.com.mx/project_name/repo_name</code>
```

The response i get is:

> fatal: unable to access
>   'http://git.someorganization.com.mx/project_name/repo_name/': Couldn't
>   connect to server

So, as you can see, it's changing `HTTPS` for `HTTP`, and i'm not being able to connect

Comment: Do you have sslVerify turned off? `git config --global http.sslVerify "true"`

Comment: no, the feature is on. I've tested on and off and still the same issue

Comment: Can you ping the url okay? Maybe it has nothing to do with the repo itself, it could be a DNS or firewall issue. You might also need to provide authentication before it will let you access it ie `https://user:pass@git.someorg.com/proj_name/repo_name/`